# I search shorter syntax of using service in blade file

Tags: laravel

In laravel 9 / breeze 1.11 app I have Service with interface
defined in files
app/Library/Services/DateMethodsServiceInterface.php
and
app/Library/Services/DateMethods.php

and I managed to use methods from this service in blade.php file as :

```
<?php        $dateMethods = \App::make(App\Library\Services\DateMethodsServiceInterface::class);
?>
...

    <input type="text" disabled class="editor_form_readonly" id="created_at" name="created_at" value="{{ $dateMethods->getFormattedDateTime($subscription->created_at) ?? ''}}">
```

But this syntax seemed for me not good. Are there some shorter version of this syntax, which I can use in blade files ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what syntax seems to be "not good"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this

```
view()->share([
    'myService' => app()->make(My\Service::class),
]);
```